# awk regex filter middle string

Tags: regex, awk

I want to use awk to filter some lines.
The lines in file:

```
Cached memory
Shared memory
/tmp
/data
/data/video
/var
/home
```

the output should be:

```
/tmp
/data/video
/var
/home
```

The hard is exclude non-started-with `/` and exclude `/data/.*`, the regex like `/^((?!\/).)|^((?!\/data$))*/` will not work, how should I write the awk expression? Thanks.

Comment: @anubhava ofcouse, its not so simple

Comment: Please show your attempt in question so that you get better help

Comment: If this is output from a command, see if you can find an option to make it not print the headers.

Comment: I have a feeling this is a bit like an XY problem, could i be correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use perl instead of awk:

```
perl -lne 'print unless(/\/data$|^[^\/]/)' your_file
```

Comment: Follow your regex, I wrote `awk '!/\/data$|^[^\/]/' my_file`  thanks!